# on input event goes automatically after comming back to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, alert

```
<input type='text' class='binp'>

$('.binp').on('input', function(){
    alert('lorem');
});
```

so I type something into `.binp` and go to another page
then go back using the browser's `Go Back` (history) button

and the alert `lorem` appears
and I must click on its `OK` button multiple times to close the alert

how to avoid this?
I want the alert only if I type, or delete, or paste something into the input, and not after coming back to the page

Comment: use the `'change'` event not `'input'`

Answer (score 0):

Try on blur.

```
$('.binp').on('keyup', function() {...});
```

Comment: in this case Shift, Ctrl, Esc... will also trigger the event

Comment: Try using sessionStorage to check whether it is coming back from history inside the 'input' event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show all the code, but I guess you misplaced the event registration.
Just put it under ready event handler.

Repro:

(1) input (2) press link (3) press with cursor somewhere in the opened link to focus it (4) Use `Alt+⬅` to get back (or another shortcut).

```js
// bad
$('.binp').on('input', function(){
    alert('lorem');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">link</a>
<input type='text' class='binp'>
```

Solution:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // good
  $('.binp').on('input', function(){
    alert('lorem');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">link</a>
<input type='text' class='binp'>
```

Comment: as long as the JavaScript is at the end of the page as it should be and the element exits there is not need to wrap it.